Is a pseudomonic and pseudoepic functor necessarily an equivalence of categories?
$\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}$Pseudomonic and pseudoepic functors form an appropriate 2-dimensional generalisation of monomorphisms and epimorphisms to categories.
Namely, a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is pseudomonic if it satisfies the following conditions:

Given functors $\phi,\psi\colon\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{C}$ and natural transformations $\alpha,\beta\colon\phi\Rightarrow\psi$, if we have
$$\id_{F}\star\alpha=\id_F\star\beta,$$
then $\alpha=\beta$.
Given functors $\phi,\psi\colon\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{C}$, if we have $F\circ\phi\cong F\circ\psi$ via a natural isomorphism $\beta$, then we have $\phi\cong\psi$ via a natural isomorphism $\alpha$ and $\beta=\id_F\star\alpha$.

Similarly a functor is pseudoepic if it satisfies the dual conditions, with $F$ now appearing on the right/being precomposed.
Now, a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is pseudomonic and pseudoepic iff the following conditions are satisfied:

The functor $F$ is faithful.
The functor $F$ is full on isomorphisms.
The functor $F$ is dominant, i.e. every object of $\mathcal{D}$ is a retract of an object of the form $F(A)$.
The functor
$$F^*\colon\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{X}))\to\mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{X}))$$
is full, i.e.:

Given functors $\phi,\psi\colon\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{X}$, if we have $\phi\circ F\cong\psi\circ F$ via a natural isomorphism $\beta$, then we have $\phi\cong\psi$ via a natural isomorphism $\alpha$ and $\beta=\alpha\star\id_F$―the dual of Item 2 in the definition of a pseudomonic functor above.



Question. Must a pseudomonic and pseudoepic functor $F$ necessarily be an equivalence of categories? If not, how badly can this fail/how far from an equivalence can $F$ be?
